# Feature selection algorithms in Scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using Scikit-learn for a binary classification task.. and I am trying to perform Feature selection using one of these methods : Correlation-based Feature Selection (CFS) Subset Evaluator and Best First search algorithm... I couldn't find any of them in the Feature selection module ! are they listed with another name in Scikit learn or is there any equivalent ?! because I want to repeat an experiment and they have used these algorithms in reducing there data.

Comment: ASU’s [scikit feature](http://featureselection.asu.edu/) is available as a Python package (Ayan Das has already mentioned it, but only referring to the Matlab implementation). It includes a [CFS algorithm](http://featureselection.asu.edu/html/skfeature.function.statistical_based.CFS.html) and many other similarity based and statistical based functions (ReliefF, Chi-square, …).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [`sklearn.feature_selection`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.feature_selection): 
[`SelectKBest`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest) and [`SelectPercentile`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectPercentile.html#sklearn.feature_selection.SelectPercentile) assess subset performance, and [`RFE`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html#sklearn.feature_selection.RFE) does recursive feature elimination.

As for Best First Search, see [Smart Feature Selection with scikit-learn and BigML’s API](http://blog.bigml.com/2014/02/26/smart-feature-selection-with-scikit-learn-and-bigmls-api/).

I am very skeptical you'll be able to exactly reproduce some experimental results based on the names of the algorithms used, FWIW.